# How do I find a sample referenced in Android docs?

Tags: android

This may seem silly to hear but all the references to any samples from the Android docs are now redirecting to: https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html

On this page, searching for "Animation" or the mentioned sample name returns no results. For example, on the [doc page about animation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#property-vs-view), there is reference to the *[bouncing balls](https://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/BouncingBalls.html)* sample with a link but it leads to nowhere. The same thing is happening for all the other sample links.

I wanted to access all the samples for Animation APIs, how do I go about finding the samples?

Answer (score -1):

As per google answer [https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66879100]

It appears that the following link on developer.android.com: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#choreography

...will take you to the source code for the "Bouncing Balls" sample: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/BouncingBalls.java

I hope you can find other too! Thanks